# chromium is causing a lot of IOWAIT, what to do?

Tags: 20.04, chromium, iowait

ubuntu 20.04

This high iowait is very problematic... if I need to install, lets say `kate` and it will download 73MB and extract it, with chromium running it would take about 1h, when I close it it takes about 5min.

I updated all extensions now (I block them from being updated, to not spend internet data and to prevent some messy updates that happen sometimes when it auto updates, by setting all "update_url" to "https://127.0.0.1", so I reverted it).

So again, this is causing too much trouble and I want to move away if it can't be fixed. I will need to move all my huge lot of bookmarks to some other browser essentially.

btw, it also has high memory usage and sometimes even high cpu usage.

My pc is not out of ram as suggested here: https://askubuntu.com/a/219480/46437, so I understand it is not a swapping problem related to chromium (the swap is almost empty anyway).

Sometimes the iowait problem stops too. But is randomly comes back with fury and rage making my machine almost unusable again (until I SIGSTOP all chromium processes and wait a bit). Could be some messy extension? I have a lot of extensions running. But it wasnt causing trouble when it was ubuntu 18.04.

Obs.: I created a script that when chromium is minimized it is SIGTOPped, and when restored is SIGCONTinued (all it's threads), this way it is less troublesome and I can continue using it until they fix it.